# Email Notifications on Interesting Questions

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another answers.ros.org email possible bug...

For questions that match my interesting tags, I only get emails when the questions are edited/answered/commented on, not when the question is originally asked.

Is this happening for anyone else? If so, I'll take my question upstream to the AskBot people.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10438/email-notifications-on-interesting-questions/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-06-29

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a number of bugs in the email notification at the moment.  There have been a few updates upstream which we haven't had time to deploy on our system.  Depending on the person you can get from all to none of the appropriate notifications. We hope to upgrade soon and see if things improve.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-08-24**:
Is that still the case right now? I also have some tag subscriptions for which I did not get an email. Sometimes they get through, however.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-06-29**:
OK. As long as its not just me. This is better than getting too many emails anyway.